# How can I resolve a "No such xattr: com.apple.quarantine" error and path error for arduino ide?

Tags: macos, arduino

I am trying to update my arduino IDE to a newer version so that it will work on IOS Catalina. I am following some instructions on how to make them compatible but I am stuck on this step. I am meant to put this command in:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /usr/local/bin/avrdude
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
xattr: /usr/local/bin/avrdude: No such xattr: com.apple.quarantine
```

I am not sure what I did wrong because when I type in this command:

```
sudo mv avrdude /usr/local/bin
```

The result I get is:

```
avrdude and /usr/local/bin/avrdude are identical
```

which tells me that the file is in the correct position (I think).
My path in the .zshrc is currently set to:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/avr/bin:$PATH
```

but when I type in:

```
printenv PATH
```

I get something different than the path listed above.
I am sure this is part of the problem, but I am not sure where to begin looking.

Comment: Files downloaded from the Net are quarantined by Apple by setting the attribute you mention. The `xattr` command deletes this attribute so you don't get problems when you run it. The fact it doesn't have that attribute should just mean the file is already ok to run, so I would be inclined to press ahead without that step.

Answer (score -3):

When I saw...

> No such xattr: com.apple.quarantine

I became root/sudo, and ran it again and it worked without that error.

```
sudo xattr -d com.apple.quarantine \<filename\>
```